# Why is this not a Galois extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be $\mathbb{R}(X)$, the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{R}$ and $L$ be $\mathbb{C}(X)$, that of over $\mathbb{C}$. And let $F$ be $L(\sqrt[3]{X+i})$ I want to show that field extension $F/K$ is not a Galois extension.

my idea: Since the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{X+i}$ over $K$ is $t^6-2Xt^3+X^2+1$, the Galois closure of $F$ over $K$ is $\mathbb{C}(\sqrt[3]{X+i},\sqrt[3]{X-i})$. So what I have to show is $\sqrt[3]{X-i}\notin F$. But how should I prove? The questions like this bother me always. Please give me advice.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}(X,\sqrt[3]{X+i}) = \mathbb{C}(T),T=\sqrt[3]{X+i}$ and it doesn't contain $\sqrt[3]{T^3-2i}$. I would also take a look at $\mathbb{C}(X,\sqrt[3]{X^2+a})$ (an elliptic curve)

Comment: Why does it not contain $\sqrt[3]{T^3-2i}$?

Comment: Does it look like a rational function in $T$ ? How many distincts roots $T^3-2i$ does have ?

Comment: I see. I was confused. It looks easy when $F$ is written as $\mathbb{C}(T)$:) Thank you for your advice.